# Tempo Marks On Each Part Individually, but not in Score

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond

I have a part that looks like this:

[image]

And another like this:

[image]

What is the best way to make the score look like this:

[image]

(only one "Adagio") without having to change the lilypond source files for each publication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `\tempo "Adagio"` in both places. `RehearsalMark` sits by default at score level, so within one score there will only be one `RehearsalMark` at the same time.